Error following the tutorial Authorize specific nodes
i am following the tutorial Authorize specific nodes, but when i arrive to the point where i have to add the line
construct_runtime!(
pub enum Runtime where
    Block = Block,
    NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
    UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
    NodeAuthorization: pallet_node_authorization::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>},
    }
);

I received the following error:
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v0.0.0 (/home/nicolas/projects/tesis-polkadot/nuevo-template/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/nicolas/projects/tesis-polkadot/nuevo-template/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-0eb0c983ccd249f6/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: env -u CARGO_ENCODED_RUSTFLAGS -u RUSTC CARGO_TARGET_DIR="/home/nicolas/projects/tesis-polkadot/nuevo-template/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target" RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP="1" RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  --cfg substrate_runtime " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/home/nicolas/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/home/nicolas/projects/tesis-polkadot/nuevo-template/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release" "-Z" "build-std"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.78.0 (9b00956e5 2024-04-29)


  --- stderr
     Compiling node-template-runtime v0.0.0 (/home/nicolas/projects/tesis-polkadot/nuevo-template/substrate-node-template/runtime)
  warning: unstable feature specified for `-Ctarget-feature`: `sign-ext`
    |
    = note: this feature is not stably supported; its behavior can change in the future

  warning: `pallet-template` (lib) generated 1 warning
  error: no rules expected the token `your_tt_return`
     --> /home/nicolas/projects/tesis-polkadot/nuevo-template/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:614:1
      |
  614 | / construct_runtime!(
  615 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  616 | |         Block = Block,
  617 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  621 | |         }
  622 | |     );
      | |_____^ no rules expected this token in macro call
      |
     ::: /home/nicolas/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tt-call-1.0.9/src/lib.rs:500:13
      |
  500 |               $input:ident = [{ $($tokens:tt)* }]
      |               ------------
      |
  note: while trying to match `frame_support`
     --> /home/nicolas/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/frame/node-authorization/src/lib.rs:55:1
      |
  55  | #[frame_support::pallet]
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      = note: captured metavariables except for `:tt`, `:ident` and `:lifetime` cannot be compared to other tokens
      = note: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/macros-by-example.html#forwarding-a-matched-fragment> for more information
      = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::__private::tt_call` which comes from the expansion of the attribute macro `frame_support::pallet` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_system` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/nicolas/projects/tesis-polkadot/nuevo-template/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-09284c8a52a37113.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/nicolas/projects/tesis-polkadot/nuevo-template/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-104ca23f9494bb67.rmeta

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0152`.
  error: could not compile `node-template-runtime` (lib) due to 2 previous errors

My runtime/lib file is the following:
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[cfg(feature = "std")]
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/wasm_binary.rs"));
parameter_types! {
    pub const MaxWellKnownNodes: u32 = 8;
    pub const MaxPeerIdLength: u32 = 128;
}


use frame_system::EnsureRoot; // causa error


use pallet_grandpa::AuthorityId as GrandpaId;
use sp_api::impl_runtime_apis;
use sp_consensus_aura::sr25519::AuthorityId as AuraId;
use sp_core::{crypto::KeyTypeId, OpaqueMetadata};
use sp_runtime::{
    create_runtime_str, generic, impl_opaque_keys,
    traits::{BlakeTwo256, Block as BlockT, IdentifyAccount, NumberFor, One, Verify},
    transaction_validity::{TransactionSource, TransactionValidity},
    ApplyExtrinsicResult, MultiSignature,
};
use sp_std::prelude::*;
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
use sp_version::NativeVersion;
use sp_version::RuntimeVersion;

use frame_support::genesis_builder_helper::{build_config, create_default_config};
pub use frame_support::{
    construct_runtime, derive_impl, parameter_types,
    traits::{
        ConstBool, ConstU128, ConstU32, ConstU64, ConstU8, KeyOwnerProofSystem, Randomness,
        StorageInfo,
    },
    weights::{
        constants::{
            BlockExecutionWeight, ExtrinsicBaseWeight, RocksDbWeight, WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND,
        },
        IdentityFee, Weight,
    },
    StorageValue,
};
pub use frame_system::Call as SystemCall;
pub use pallet_balances::Call as BalancesCall;
pub use pallet_timestamp::Call as TimestampCall;
use pallet_transaction_payment::{ConstFeeMultiplier, CurrencyAdapter, Multiplier};
#[cfg(any(feature = "std", test))]
pub use sp_runtime::BuildStorage;
pub use sp_runtime::{Perbill, Permill};

/// Import the template pallet.
pub use pallet_template;

/// An index to a block.
pub type BlockNumber = u32;

/// Alias to 512-bit hash when used in the context of a transaction signature on the chain.
pub type Signature = MultiSignature;

/// Some way of identifying an account on the chain. We intentionally make it equivalent
/// to the public key of our transaction signing scheme.
pub type AccountId = <<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;

/// Balance of an account.
pub type Balance = u128;

/// Index of a transaction in the chain.
pub type Nonce = u32;

/// A hash of some data used by the chain.
pub type Hash = sp_core::H256;

/// Opaque types. These are used by the CLI to instantiate machinery that don't need to know
/// the specifics of the runtime. They can then be made to be agnostic over specific formats
/// of data like extrinsics, allowing for them to continue syncing the network through upgrades
/// to even the core data structures.
pub mod opaque {
    use super::*;

    pub use sp_runtime::OpaqueExtrinsic as UncheckedExtrinsic;

    /// Opaque block header type.
    pub type Header = generic::Header<BlockNumber, BlakeTwo256>;
    /// Opaque block type.
    pub type Block = generic::Block<Header, UncheckedExtrinsic>;
    /// Opaque block identifier type.
    pub type BlockId = generic::BlockId<Block>;

    impl_opaque_keys! {
        pub struct SessionKeys {
            pub aura: Aura,
            pub grandpa: Grandpa,
        }
    }
}

// To learn more about runtime versioning, see:
// https://docs.substrate.io/main-docs/build/upgrade#runtime-versioning
#[sp_version::runtime_version]
pub const VERSION: RuntimeVersion = RuntimeVersion {
    spec_name: create_runtime_str!("solochain-template-runtime"),
    impl_name: create_runtime_str!("solochain-template-runtime"),
    authoring_version: 1,
    // The version of the runtime specification. A full node will not attempt to use its native
    //   runtime in substitute for the on-chain Wasm runtime unless all of `spec_name`,
    //   `spec_version`, and `authoring_version` are the same between Wasm and native.
    // This value is set to 100 to notify Polkadot-JS App (https://polkadot.js.org/apps) to use
    //   the compatible custom types.
    spec_version: 100,
    impl_version: 1,
    apis: RUNTIME_API_VERSIONS,
    transaction_version: 1,
    state_version: 1,
};

/// This determines the average expected block time that we are targeting.
/// Blocks will be produced at a minimum duration defined by `SLOT_DURATION`.
/// `SLOT_DURATION` is picked up by `pallet_timestamp` which is in turn picked
/// up by `pallet_aura` to implement `fn slot_duration()`.
///
/// Change this to adjust the block time.
pub const MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK: u64 = 6000;

// NOTE: Currently it is not possible to change the slot duration after the chain has started.
//   Attempting to do so will brick block production.
pub const SLOT_DURATION: u64 = MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK;

// Time is measured by number of blocks.
pub const MINUTES: BlockNumber = 60_000 / (MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK as BlockNumber);
pub const HOURS: BlockNumber = MINUTES * 60;
pub const DAYS: BlockNumber = HOURS * 24;

/// The version information used to identify this runtime when compiled natively.
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
pub fn native_version() -> NativeVersion {
    NativeVersion { runtime_version: VERSION, can_author_with: Default::default() }
}

const NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(75);

parameter_types! {
    pub const BlockHashCount: BlockNumber = 2400;
    pub const Version: RuntimeVersion = VERSION;
    /// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block time.
    pub BlockWeights: frame_system::limits::BlockWeights =
        frame_system::limits::BlockWeights::with_sensible_defaults(
            Weight::from_parts(2u64 * WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND, u64::MAX),
            NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO,
        );
    pub BlockLength: frame_system::limits::BlockLength = frame_system::limits::BlockLength
        ::max_with_normal_ratio(5 * 1024 * 1024, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
    pub const SS58Prefix: u8 = 42;
}

/// The default types are being injected by [`derive_impl`](`frame_support::derive_impl`) from
/// [`SoloChainDefaultConfig`](`struct@frame_system::config_preludes::SolochainDefaultConfig`),
/// but overridden as needed.
#[derive_impl(frame_system::config_preludes::SolochainDefaultConfig as frame_system::DefaultConfig)]
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    /// The block type for the runtime.
    type Block = Block;
    /// Block & extrinsics weights: base values and limits.
    type BlockWeights = BlockWeights;
    /// The maximum length of a block (in bytes).
    type BlockLength = BlockLength;
    /// The identifier used to distinguish between accounts.
    type AccountId = AccountId;
    /// The type for storing how many extrinsics an account has signed.
    type Nonce = Nonce;
    /// The type for hashing blocks and tries.
    type Hash = Hash;
    /// Maximum number of block number to block hash mappings to keep (oldest pruned first).
    type BlockHashCount = BlockHashCount;
    /// The weight of database operations that the runtime can invoke.
    type DbWeight = RocksDbWeight;
    /// Version of the runtime.
    type Version = Version;
    /// The data to be stored in an account.
    type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<Balance>;
    /// This is used as an identifier of the chain. 42 is the generic substrate prefix.
    type SS58Prefix = SS58Prefix;
    type MaxConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<16>;
}

impl pallet_aura::Config for Runtime {
    type AuthorityId = AuraId;
    type DisabledValidators = ();
    type MaxAuthorities = ConstU32<32>;
    type AllowMultipleBlocksPerSlot = ConstBool<false>;

    #[cfg(feature = "experimental")]
    type SlotDuration = pallet_aura::MinimumPeriodTimesTwo<Runtime>;
}

impl pallet_grandpa::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;

    type WeightInfo = ();
    type MaxAuthorities = ConstU32<32>;
    type MaxNominators = ConstU32<0>;
    type MaxSetIdSessionEntries = ConstU64<0>;

    type KeyOwnerProof = sp_core::Void;
    type EquivocationReportSystem = ();
}

impl pallet_timestamp::Config for Runtime {
    /// A timestamp: milliseconds since the unix epoch.
    type Moment = u64;
    type OnTimestampSet = Aura;
    type MinimumPeriod = ConstU64<{ SLOT_DURATION / 2 }>;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}

/// Existential deposit.
pub const EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT: u128 = 500;

impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
    type MaxLocks = ConstU32<50>;
    type MaxReserves = ();
    type ReserveIdentifier = [u8; 8];
    /// The type for recording an account's balance.
    type Balance = Balance;
    /// The ubiquitous event type.
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type DustRemoval = ();
    type ExistentialDeposit = ConstU128<EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT>;
    type AccountStore = System;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_balances::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type FreezeIdentifier = ();
    type MaxFreezes = ();
    type RuntimeHoldReason = ();
    type RuntimeFreezeReason = ();
}

parameter_types! {
    pub FeeMultiplier: Multiplier = Multiplier::one();
}

impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, ()>;
    type OperationalFeeMultiplier = ConstU8<5>;
    type WeightToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type LengthToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type FeeMultiplierUpdate = ConstFeeMultiplier<FeeMultiplier>;
}

impl pallet_sudo::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_sudo::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}

/// Configure the pallet-template in pallets/template.
impl pallet_template::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_template::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}

/// Esto lo agregue según la guia
impl pallet_node_authorization::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type MaxWellKnownNodes = MaxWellKnownNodes;
    type MaxPeerIdLength = MaxPeerIdLength;
    type AddOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type RemoveOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type SwapOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type ResetOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type WeightInfo = ();
   }

// Create the runtime by composing the FRAME pallets that were previously configured.
#[frame_support::runtime]
mod runtime {
    #[runtime::runtime]
    #[runtime::derive(
        RuntimeCall,
        RuntimeEvent,
        RuntimeError,
        RuntimeOrigin,
        RuntimeFreezeReason,
        RuntimeHoldReason,
        RuntimeSlashReason,
        RuntimeLockId,
        RuntimeTask
    )]
    pub struct Runtime;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(0)]
    pub type System = frame_system;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(1)]
    pub type Timestamp = pallet_timestamp;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(2)]
    pub type Aura = pallet_aura;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(3)]
    pub type Grandpa = pallet_grandpa;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(4)]
    pub type Balances = pallet_balances;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(5)]
    pub type TransactionPayment = pallet_transaction_payment;

    #[runtime::pallet_index(6)]
    pub type Sudo = pallet_sudo;

    // Include the custom logic from the pallet-template in the runtime.
    #[runtime::pallet_index(7)]
    pub type TemplateModule = pallet_template;

    // Adición de runtime
    //#[runtime::pallet_index(8)]
    //pub type NodeAuthorization = pallet_node_authorization;
}

/// The address format for describing accounts.
pub type Address = sp_runtime::MultiAddress<AccountId, ()>;
/// Block header type as expected by this runtime.
pub type Header = generic::Header<BlockNumber, BlakeTwo256>;
/// Block type as expected by this runtime.
pub type Block = generic::Block<Header, UncheckedExtrinsic>;
/// The SignedExtension to the basic transaction logic.
pub type SignedExtra = (
    frame_system::CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckTxVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckGenesis<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckEra<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckNonce<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckWeight<Runtime>,
    pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>,
);

/// All migrations of the runtime, aside from the ones declared in the pallets.
///
/// This can be a tuple of types, each implementing `OnRuntimeUpgrade`.
#[allow(unused_parens)]
type Migrations = ();

/// Unchecked extrinsic type as expected by this runtime.
pub type UncheckedExtrinsic =
    generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, RuntimeCall, Signature, SignedExtra>;
/// The payload being signed in transactions.
pub type SignedPayload = generic::SignedPayload<RuntimeCall, SignedExtra>;
/// Executive: handles dispatch to the various modules.
pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    Migrations,
>;

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
mod benches {
    frame_benchmarking::define_benchmarks!(
        [frame_benchmarking, BaselineBench::<Runtime>]
        [frame_system, SystemBench::<Runtime>]
        [pallet_balances, Balances]
        [pallet_timestamp, Timestamp]
        [pallet_sudo, Sudo]
        [pallet_template, TemplateModule]
    );
}

impl_runtime_apis! {
    impl sp_api::Core<Block> for Runtime {
        fn version() -> RuntimeVersion {
            VERSION
        }

        fn execute_block(block: Block) {
            Executive::execute_block(block);
        }

        fn initialize_block(header: &<Block as BlockT>::Header) -> sp_runtime::ExtrinsicInclusionMode {
            Executive::initialize_block(header)
        }
    }

    impl sp_api::Metadata<Block> for Runtime {
        fn metadata() -> OpaqueMetadata {
            OpaqueMetadata::new(Runtime::metadata().into())
        }

        fn metadata_at_version(version: u32) -> Option<OpaqueMetadata> {
            Runtime::metadata_at_version(version)
        }

        fn metadata_versions() -> sp_std::vec::Vec<u32> {
            Runtime::metadata_versions()
        }
    }

    impl sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder<Block> for Runtime {
        fn apply_extrinsic(extrinsic: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic) -> ApplyExtrinsicResult {
            Executive::apply_extrinsic(extrinsic)
        }

        fn finalize_block() -> <Block as BlockT>::Header {
            Executive::finalize_block()
        }

        fn inherent_extrinsics(data: sp_inherents::InherentData) -> Vec<<Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic> {
            data.create_extrinsics()
        }

        fn check_inherents(
            block: Block,
            data: sp_inherents::InherentData,
        ) -> sp_inherents::CheckInherentsResult {
            data.check_extrinsics(&block)
        }
    }

    impl sp_transaction_pool::runtime_api::TaggedTransactionQueue<Block> for Runtime {
        fn validate_transaction(
            source: TransactionSource,
            tx: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            block_hash: <Block as BlockT>::Hash,
        ) -> TransactionValidity {
            Executive::validate_transaction(source, tx, block_hash)
        }
    }

    impl sp_offchain::OffchainWorkerApi<Block> for Runtime {
        fn offchain_worker(header: &<Block as BlockT>::Header) {
            Executive::offchain_worker(header)
        }
    }

    impl sp_consensus_aura::AuraApi<Block, AuraId> for Runtime {
        fn slot_duration() -> sp_consensus_aura::SlotDuration {
            sp_consensus_aura::SlotDuration::from_millis(Aura::slot_duration())
        }

        fn authorities() -> Vec<AuraId> {
            Aura::authorities().into_inner()
        }
    }

    impl sp_session::SessionKeys<Block> for Runtime {
        fn generate_session_keys(seed: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<u8> {
            opaque::SessionKeys::generate(seed)
        }

        fn decode_session_keys(
            encoded: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> Option<Vec<(Vec<u8>, KeyTypeId)>> {
            opaque::SessionKeys::decode_into_raw_public_keys(&encoded)
        }
    }

    impl sp_consensus_grandpa::GrandpaApi<Block> for Runtime {
        fn grandpa_authorities() -> sp_consensus_grandpa::AuthorityList {
            Grandpa::grandpa_authorities()
        }

        fn current_set_id() -> sp_consensus_grandpa::SetId {
            Grandpa::current_set_id()
        }

        fn submit_report_equivocation_unsigned_extrinsic(
            _equivocation_proof: sp_consensus_grandpa::EquivocationProof<
                <Block as BlockT>::Hash,
                NumberFor<Block>,
            >,
            _key_owner_proof: sp_consensus_grandpa::OpaqueKeyOwnershipProof,
        ) -> Option<()> {
            None
        }

        fn generate_key_ownership_proof(
            _set_id: sp_consensus_grandpa::SetId,
            _authority_id: GrandpaId,
        ) -> Option<sp_consensus_grandpa::OpaqueKeyOwnershipProof> {
            // NOTE: this is the only implementation possible since we've
            // defined our key owner proof type as a bottom type (i.e. a type
            // with no values).
            None
        }
    }

    impl frame_system_rpc_runtime_api::AccountNonceApi<Block, AccountId, Nonce> for Runtime {
        fn account_nonce(account: AccountId) -> Nonce {
            System::account_nonce(account)
        }
    }

    impl pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentApi<Block, Balance> for Runtime {
        fn query_info(
            uxt: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::RuntimeDispatchInfo<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_info(uxt, len)
        }
        fn query_fee_details(
            uxt: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment::FeeDetails<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_fee_details(uxt, len)
        }
        fn query_weight_to_fee(weight: Weight) -> Balance {
            TransactionPayment::weight_to_fee(weight)
        }
        fn query_length_to_fee(length: u32) -> Balance {
            TransactionPayment::length_to_fee(length)
        }
    }

    impl pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentCallApi<Block, Balance, RuntimeCall>
        for Runtime
    {
        fn query_call_info(
            call: RuntimeCall,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment::RuntimeDispatchInfo<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_call_info(call, len)
        }
        fn query_call_fee_details(
            call: RuntimeCall,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment::FeeDetails<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_call_fee_details(call, len)
        }
        fn query_weight_to_fee(weight: Weight) -> Balance {
            TransactionPayment::weight_to_fee(weight)
        }
        fn query_length_to_fee(length: u32) -> Balance {
            TransactionPayment::length_to_fee(length)
        }
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    impl frame_benchmarking::Benchmark<Block> for Runtime {
        fn benchmark_metadata(extra: bool) -> (
            Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkList>,
            Vec<frame_support::traits::StorageInfo>,
        ) {
            use frame_benchmarking::{baseline, Benchmarking, BenchmarkList};
            use frame_support::traits::StorageInfoTrait;
            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use baseline::Pallet as BaselineBench;

            let mut list = Vec::<BenchmarkList>::new();
            list_benchmarks!(list, extra);

            let storage_info = AllPalletsWithSystem::storage_info();

            (list, storage_info)
        }

        fn dispatch_benchmark(
            config: frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkConfig
        ) -> Result<Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkBatch>, sp_runtime::RuntimeString> {
            use frame_benchmarking::{baseline, Benchmarking, BenchmarkBatch};
            use sp_storage::TrackedStorageKey;
            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use baseline::Pallet as BaselineBench;

            impl frame_system_benchmarking::Config for Runtime {}
            impl baseline::Config for Runtime {}

            use frame_support::traits::WhitelistedStorageKeys;
            let whitelist: Vec<TrackedStorageKey> = AllPalletsWithSystem::whitelisted_storage_keys();

            let mut batches = Vec::<BenchmarkBatch>::new();
            let params = (&config, &whitelist);
            add_benchmarks!(params, batches);

            Ok(batches)
        }
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
    impl frame_try_runtime::TryRuntime<Block> for Runtime {
        fn on_runtime_upgrade(checks: frame_try_runtime::UpgradeCheckSelect) -> (Weight, Weight) {
            // NOTE: intentional unwrap: we don't want to propagate the error backwards, and want to
            // have a backtrace here. If any of the pre/post migration checks fail, we shall stop
            // right here and right now.
            let weight = Executive::try_runtime_upgrade(checks).unwrap();
            (weight, BlockWeights::get().max_block)
        }

        fn execute_block(
            block: Block,
            state_root_check: bool,
            signature_check: bool,
            select: frame_try_runtime::TryStateSelect
        ) -> Weight {
            // NOTE: intentional unwrap: we don't want to propagate the error backwards, and want to
            // have a backtrace here.
            Executive::try_execute_block(block, state_root_check, signature_check, select).expect("execute-block failed")
        }
    }

    impl sp_genesis_builder::GenesisBuilder<Block> for Runtime {
        fn create_default_config() -> Vec<u8> {
            create_default_config::<RuntimeGenesisConfig>()
        }

        fn build_config(config: Vec<u8>) -> sp_genesis_builder::Result {
            build_config::<RuntimeGenesisConfig>(config)
        }
    }
}

construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
        {
        NodeAuthorization: pallet_node_authorization::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>},
        }
);

I tried something to fixed but i couldn't, that's why there's the new macro commented.
Edit
I have to errors:

The runtime problem
The sp_io duplicate dependency

I just read the one similar to this one, but i didn't find the solution. One answer is should i include std but i already did it and the problem must not appear in the last version which i downloaded.

This is a common issue for newcomers performing their first SDK upgrade. Carefully check the dependencies. If you still can't find the bug, attach your repo link here. Otherwise, we can't address the problem based on the information provided.

Here is the github link: https://github.com/NXHM/blockchain-permisionada.git. I am 2 days searching but i couldn´t find the mistake. Sorry for bothering and thanks for helping me

BTW, I suggest using workspace dependencies, like those in this example: https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier/blob/5f13853d296f4e08435da1b40d48f7338f663070/Cargo.toml#L50-L203. This could help prevent some of these issues.

WalquerX found the error. The construct_runtime! macro from substrate tutorial is outdated, is not what is shown there. There is a V2 from the macro, and also the import form of node-authorization is outdated and should be change it
